# Twilio functions realTimeStatistics is not a function

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I am building a twilio function but I am getting an error using a function that's in the documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/workspace-statistics?code-sample=code-retrieve-workspace-real-time-statistics&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) I know the npm version of Twilio is 3.6.3 from (functions/configure).

```
client.taskrouter.workspaces(workspaceSid)
        .realTimeStatistics()
        .fetch()
        .then(workspace_real_time_statistics => { agentsActive = workspace_real_time_statistics.total_workers});
```

when running the function I get the following error:

client.taskrouter.workspaces(...).realTimeStatistics is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Node Helper Library Details.

It looks like it was possibly added in 3.7.0?

[twilio-node changelog](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/CHANGES.md#2017-09-28-version-370)

Comment: can you please be more descriptive here? Im not sure this answers the questions directly.

Comment: If you are using Twilio Functions, once logged into the Twilio Console, visit this URL, https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/configure, and change the twilio client NPM module to a more recent version, say 3.33.2 and make sure to save.